# Outlook 2010 Predefine a reply

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I would like to predefine a reply in Outlook 2010. So, if I'd send a mail to someone and this person clicks on reply, he would already have part of the mail written. For example, he would see a text "Dear Len, I would like to come to your office at " and he would only have to fill in a date and hour.
I know in Wordpress it is more or less possible to define for example the subject etc in the 'mailto' command.

Is this possible? If yes, how can I enforce this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any functionality to allow this.

The best I can think of is attaching a pre-written email (Send an email to yourself with the subject and body already filled, then attach that to it) they could forward to you, but otherwise there's no way, and even this way wouldn't work very well as different email clients would likely handle it in a different way.

Sorry!